# Can no longer set printer duplex option (but `lpr` works with duplex)

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, printing, cups-lpd, duplex-printing

I can no longer set duplex and other printer options (Kubuntu 16.04).

I have a Ricoh Aficio SP 4310N printer, with the matching driver selected as in the screenshots below. The only option I have under "Printer Options" is to query the printer for the default options. However, when I click that, I job gets sent with the name "Set Default Options", which fails with status "Filter failed".

Printing stuff in general works well, but because of this I cannot change the double-sided printing options.

What could be the issue, or where could I start troubleshooting?

Edit: 
I recently found that LibreOffice *can* print double-sidedly, which also lead me to find that `lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge document.pdf` works and prints double-sidedly. (I found out via https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1530244.) The remaining question is why the print dialogs in all other programs, both KDE and Gnome, have the duplex printing option disabled.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Aficio SP 4310N has been discontinued and there isn't much online information available but in what I could find there's no mention of duplex.

Comment: Duplex has been working for the last few years, at least using Kubuntu 14.04 and 13.x. So the printer is definitely capable of doing it. My main question would be what could cause "query printer defaults" to return "filter failed"?

Comment: Something is wrong with driver. Try removing and adding the printer again.